# Swift: CollectionView Labels and Sliders on different clases an collections

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel, uislider

I have Two collections in one view, and one have sliders and another have  labels.. the slider change the value of the label, but doesn't, in the console really change the values, but the label don't.. this is my code:

the class `LabelCollection`: `UICollectionViewCell`.... and my object

```
let mylabel: UIlabel =  {
    let label = Uilabel()
    label.text = "90"
    return label
}()
```

and the slider on the other class sliderCollection: `UICollectionViewCell`....

```
let mySlider: UISlider = {
   let slider = UISlider()
    slider.maximumValue = 100
    slider.value = 50
    slider.tintColor = UIColor.white
    slider.thumbTintColor = UIColor.white
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.valueChangeImageLabel), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)      
    return slider
}()
```

and this is the function to change the value:

```
@objc func valueChangeImageLabel(sender: UISlider) {

    let labelOnVC = LabelCollection()
    let textLabel = labelOnVC.myLabel

    let value = Int(sender.value)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        labelText.text = String(value)
        print("Slider Value: \(value)")
        print("Label Value: \(String(describing: myLabel.text))")
    }
```

when I run the app, on my console change the value of both, slider and label, but the label on the view.. do nothing...

someone can help?

Comment: `let labelOnVC = LabelCollection()` That's creating a WHOLE NEW object. I don't think that's the one you are thinking of that was previously created.

Comment: ohh, I understand and thanks a lot Larme... what can I do to call the object label from another class... I try this... Labelcolletion().myLabel.text = String(value)  actually use swift 4

Comment: `LabelCollection()` That's the part where in fact you are creating a whole new object, so `Labelcolletion().myLabel.text = String(value)` won't work at all.